# Displaying an image larger than it is with CSS

Tags: css, image, height, width

I have written a fairly basic javascript function that when an image is clicked on a full sized version appears in the foreground.

The image is set with max-width and max-height numbers in a CSS file such that it leaves some space around the outside and it preserves it's own proportions.

The problem is that if the image happens to not be large, or the screen of the users device has a very high pixel density then the 'larger' image might not be any larger.

Is there a way I can keep proportions, not exceed say 90% on either side, but set the largest dimension to be 90%.

The closest similar method I have found is the fill option for backgrounds.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Set the `width` and `height` of the image to a relative value like `100% - (margin + border + padding)` so that it will be stretched regardless of its actual dimensions.

Using `max-width` and `max-height` is a nice way to restrain your image from growing beyond specific proporitions, but leaves room for the image to decide what size it wants to be within those bounds. You say you do not want this, thus set `width` and `height` as well.

Comment: By setting width and height I loss the correct proportions, it's important to conserve this.

Comment: If you set `width: 100%;` and `height: auto;`, the proportions should normally be preserved.

Comment: If I use `width: 100%;` and `height: auto;` then a portrait image will be set to fill the width, the height will then try to keep proportions until it sees that it will exceed the max height, ie it just stretches the image to fill the entire area.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed that image in div tag and apply css property width:100% to image and on click of image increase the width of div proportionately as per the resolution. In this scenario image with less width than parent div gets adjusted as per width of parent div.

Comment: What if the image is a portrait? It will then be larger than the screen.

Comment: We are including that image in parent div, so it will get adjusted as per width of parent div

Comment: But a portait image should be constrained by it's height, not width.